# How do I scrape the number which denotes the maximum number of pages in a website before parsing a URL in a scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape this website https://phdessay.com/free-essays/.

I need to find the maximum number of pages so that I can append the URLs with page numbers to the start_urls list. I'm not able to figure out how to do that.

Here's my code so far,

```
class PhdessaysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phdessays'
    start_urls = ['https://phdessay.com/free-essays/']

    def parse(self, response):
        all_essay_urls = response.css('.phdessay-card-read::attr(href)').getall()
        for essay_url in all_essay_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(essay_url, callback=self.parse_essay_contents)


    def parse_essay_contents(self, response):
        items = PhdEssaysItem()
        essay_title = response.css('.site-title::text').get()
        essay_url = response.request.url
        items['essay_title'] = essay_title
        items['essay_url'] = essay_url
        yield items
```

In the above code, I'm following each essay to it's individual page and am scraping the URL and the title (I will be scraping the content which is the reason why I'm following the individual essay URL).

This works just fine for the starting page; but there are about 1677 pages which might change in the future. I would like to scrape this `maximum_no_of_pages` number and then append all links with all page numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is to find the last page number and then do a range loop to yield next pages requests.

Something like this:

```py
class PhdessaysSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'phdessays'
    start_urls = ['https://phdessay.com/free-essays/']

    def parse(self, response):
        max_page = int(response.css('.page-numbers::text').getall()[-1])
        for page_number in range(1, max_page + 1):
            page_url = f'https://phdessay.com/free-essays/page/{page_number}/'
            yield scrapy.Request(page_url, callback=self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        all_essay_urls = response.css('.phdessay-card-read::attr(href)').getall()
        for essay_url in all_essay_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(essay_url, callback=self.parse_essay_contents)

    def parse_essay_contents(self, response):
        items = PhdEssaysItem()
        essay_title = response.css('.site-title::text').get()
        essay_url = response.request.url
        items['essay_title'] = essay_title
        items['essay_url'] = essay_url
        yield items
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm familiar with this concept already. I'm trying to solve a problem where you can't distinguish and uniquely identify the next page info in the pagination. There's also no option which provides functionality similar to "next page". So, I was hoping that I could populate the maximum number of pages in  `max_pages ` variable and append all links to the `start_urls` list. My bad, I should've specified it in the post.

Comment: Sorry, I read your question too quickly. I've edited my question for something more helpful for you :)